# C - Why am I getting two characters excpet one as output?

Tags: c, switch-statement, printf

So I create this small program to represent my problem. Run program enter 'a' press ENTER.

C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char o;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("> ");
        scanf("%c",&o);
        switch(o)
        {
        case 'a' :
            printf("%c\n",o);
            break;
        case 'q' :
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
> a
a
> > *(waiting for input)*
```

What I expected it to be:

```
> a
a
> *(waiting for input)*
```

Please give me some advice how to get my problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks guys, I had no clue how scanf works. Really helped me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `\n` on `stdin` after you scan out `a`. Either call `getchar()` after you have grabbed the character or change your `scanf` to `scanf("%c%*c", &o)`. Because of this, the second time your loop looks for input, it will already have the `\n` waiting, and it will switch on that value, do nothing, and prompt again.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%c",&o);` will read exactly one character, without skipping whitespace. In other words, it will treat newlines, tabs, and space characters as valid inputs.

To skip the whitespace characters, use

```
scanf(" %c",&o); 
       ^---- note the extra space here
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `getchar()` after your `scanf`.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you also explained why this works.

Answer (score 0):

After you type the input and hit 'Enter', the '\n' gets stored in the input buffer, and the next scanf takes '\n' as the input. Hence, you first need to get rid of the newline character. This can be achieved by using another variable (`clr` in the code below) to store the newline character. Here's the modification :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
char o,clr;    
while(1)
{
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%c",&o);
    clr=getchar();    // line added
    switch(o)
    {
    case 'a' :
        printf("%c\n",o);
        break;
    case 'q' :
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```